# How to solve delay of progressView's movement animation

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

Currently, I'm downloading data from a web server by calling a method `fetchProducts`. This is done in another separate thread. As I successfully download fifty items inside the method stated above, I `post` a notification to the `[NSNotification defaultCenter]` through the method call `postNotificationName: object:` which is being listened to by the `Observer`. Take note that this `Observer` is another `ViewController` with the selector `updateProductsBeingDownloadedCount:`. Now as the `Observer` gets the notification, I set the property of my `progressView` and a label that tells the progress. Below is the code I do this change in UI.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if ([notif.name isEqualToString:@"DownloadingProducts"]) {

        [self.progressBar setProgress:self.progress animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"SetupStore: progress bar value is %.0f", self.progressBar.progress);

        self.progressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading %.0f%% done...", self.progress * 100];
        NSLog(@"SetupStore: progress label value is %@", self.progressLabel.text);
        [self.view reloadInputViews];
    }
});
```

The idea is to move the `progressView` simultaneously as more items were being downloaded until it is finished. In my case, the `progressView`'s animation will just start right after the items were already downloaded, hence a delay. Kindly enlighten me on this.

Comment: ***Just bloody move your synchronous network operations to a background thread.***

Comment: What @H2CO3 said, probably, but it is hard to tell without seeing any of your code.

Comment: @H2CO3 those were already in a separate thread. Kindly see edited post.

Comment: But, is your "other separate thread" running in the background, or on the main thread?  It sounds as if it is running on the main thread.

Comment: @lnafziger I did another thread through this `dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("iMonggo All Items Fetcher", NULL);` and `dispatch_sync(fetchQ, ^{ });` and it's running in the background

Comment: dispatch_sync runs on the current thread, which I'm assuming is your main thread?